# What is eating my plants leaves?

Tags: tomatoes, raspberries

I don't know what this bug is, but I'm sure it's why I have holes on my tomato plants leaves and raspberries plants leaves. [image]

Comment: Can you post some closeups of the leaf damage for the raspberry and tomato plants?  What makes you think it is this bug vs. something else?

Comment: It is important to discover what is making holes but it usually is not life threatening.  A little disfigurement is always expected and okay. I see one tiny hole on these raspberries and I also see they need some fertilizer....

Comment: Plastic, sigh.  Are weeds really that much of a problem?  Also a great place for some organisms to hide and thrive and hang out.  This is also the time for flea beetles and the best thing I've found is a trap crop.  Planting stuff they like far better than your raspberries and tomatoes...mustards, spinach.  Plant a bunch of that and allow them to go nuts.  They will disappear within a month.  If that tiny hole is indicative of what you are trying to show, that is flea beetle.  Give them a banquet you don't care much about.  Easy to regrow as well as a few holes will not kill even the trap crop

Answer (score 2):

My guess (and given how blurry the image is, a guess seems all that is possible) is an [*Ephemeroptera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mayfly):

[image: Ephemeroptera]

If it is a mayfly it would not account for the holes in your leaves.

Answer (score 1):

Inchworms can hide underneath leaves and will devestate plants,  check under every leaf.  They were all over my big boy tomato plants right as they were coming in. Large grasshoppers may also cause damage they dont usually stick around though, youll catch them every now and again.

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely a Mayfly I concur. It looks exactly like one. I have seen many Mayflies. I am absolutely positive about that.

Mayflies won't harm plants. More or less fertilize it after dying so briefly after maturing. You may simply read into these insects online if you'd like to know more. The picture is clear enough, that every characteristic matches up to the normal Mayfly.

Comment: If you are going to edit my post, then edit it correctly or dont edit it at all,  you left it " that ever characteristic matches up" that was suppose to read " that every characteristic matches up" dont edit my post, its how I speak, when you change it, its not me talking.